# How do I install pygame without installing extra modules before?

Tags: python, pygame, mp3

I recently started learning to use Python and built in modules such as Tkinter. However in order to finish the programme I am making, I need to use pygame to open a music file in the programme. I have what I am sure is the correct pygame files (see image) but I have no clue how to actually add it to be able to use when coding in Python. (Get the error that the module cannot be found).

If there is an intergrated Python module that will allow me to open music files then I would be interested in knowing if that is an easier method.

Pygame files:

[image]

Comment: What OS did you use? And how you install pygame?

Comment: @kvorobiev The screenshot indicates Windows.

Comment: I'm currently on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

In a web browser go to http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml locate the package that matches your environment and follow the instructions, (either download and run or type the command).